# Unrecognised selector sent to instance by NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When i want to update a label via NSNotificationCenter is get an Runtime error but i don't know why. Slectors are named same.

ViewController2

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: UIButton) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("TimeRepairID", object: nil)
}
```

ViewController

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setTimeRepair", name: "TimeRepairID", object: nil)  
}

func setTimeRepair(notification: NSNotification){
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", RepairTime.sharedInstance.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(RepairTime.sharedInstance.ReadyForPickup())
}
```

so every time i press the save button in ViewController2 the app crashes with unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x13e63bd40 know any

Comment: see code, you misses : after selector name.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  **What is the *full* error message??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misses `:` after selector name as you are passing NSNotification as argument.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setTimeRepair:", name: "TimeRepairID", object: nil)
}

func setTimeRepair(notification: NSNotification){
    CurrentTimerepair.text = String(format:"%.1f", RepairTime.sharedInstance.TimeOfRepair())
    RFPTime.text = String(RepairTime.sharedInstance.ReadyForPickup())
}
```

Comment: only when it has argument

Comment: Remember to remove yourself as an observer in the deinit or viewDidDisappear method as well, eg:
    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

Comment: where i must implement the deinit ? in viewController ? @mofojed

Comment: Yes, see example: http://natashatherobot.com/ios8-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/